# Local Background Image Not Loading

Tags: css, image, background, local

This one seems simple but wont work for some reason. I have a background-image (locally) in css like this:

```
#header { background-image: url('/../img/students.jpg'); }
/*also tried this */ #header { background-image: url('../img/students.jpg'); }
```

But it wont load. Here is the directory structure:

```
---css
-------styles.css
---img
-------students.jpg
```

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This **should** have worked.

```
#header { 
    background-image: url('../img/students.jpg'); 
}
```

Also, this should work as well

```
#header { 
    background-image: url('/img/students.jpg'); 
}
```

My guess is that you're having some caching issues. Your first attempt was wrong, `/../img/students.jpg` goes one level above the document root, which is not possible. Maybe this css with this error has been cached by your browser, try hitting CTRL + F5 several times (or completly clear the browser's cache) once you have fixed your css file with one of the solutions above.